# Limitations to the Excel INDIRECT() Function

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

If I have numerical data in **A1** and **A2** then:

```
=SUM(A1:A2)
```

works and:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("A1:A2"))
```

works and:

```
=SUM(A1,A2)
```

works but:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("A1,A2"))
```

does not work.  I am guessing that this is because `"A1,A2"` is not a valid cell reference.

Can anyone explain why this is so, or point me to some online documentation that gives the explanation ??

Comment: Your guess is correct.  It isn't clear exactly what you're looking for (you have ready access to documentation on INDIRECT's syntax, which will confirm what you've written).  It seems like you've included your own answer.  I'm coming up empty on what else could be said.

Comment: You have to write: =Sum(Indirect("A1"),Indirect("A2")) in order to have a valid answer, Indirect for each reference to sum the inside value of A1 and A2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SUM function takes a **list of** numbers or **references** as arguments.  When you separate ranges with a comma, you are sending two arguments (references) to the SUM function.

The INDIRECT function accepts **one** ref_text **argument** (and the optional a1 argument) and "returns the **reference** specified by a text string."

> [SUM function, Syntax:](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUM-function-043e1c7d-7726-4e80-8f32-07b23e057f89)
>
> **SUM(number1,[number2],...)**
>
> **number1**    (Required)
>
> The first number you want to add. The number can be like 4, a cell
>   reference like B6, or a cell range like B2:B8.
>
> **number2-255**    (Optional)
>
> This is the second number you want to add. You can specify up to 255
>   numbers in this way.

Comment: Thank you very much ! I still have not been able to find any "official" or formal definition of a "reference".

Comment: I would agree that the definition does seem a touch unclear. Consider range intersection, for example: CELL("address",D1:D10 D7:J7), for example, returns $D$7, i.e. a text string representing the unique address at which the ranges D1:D10 and D7:J7 intersect. Also note that the second (optional) parameter in the CELL function (when using a first parameter of "address") is denoted as "reference". Hence D1:D10 D1:J1 appears to be accepted as just that in this instance. However, in a construction such as =SUM(INDIRECT("D1:D10 D1:J1")) (which returns #REF!), it no longer appears to be.